# how to convert select box html to form html collactive

Tags: laravel, html-select, dropdown

Hi i have this in my controller

```
$listPatient = Patient::get();

    return view('backend.consultations.create')->with([
        'patient' => $this->patient,
        'patient_id' =>$this->patient_id,
        'listPatient' => $listPatient,
        ]);
```

and in my view i have

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        List clients
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">

         <select name="patient_id">
            <option value="0">Veillier séléctionner un patien </option>
            @foreach($listPatient as $key)
              <option value="{{$key->id}}">{{$key->nom_patient}} {{$key->prenom_patient}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select> 
    </div><!--col-lg-10-->
</div><!--form control-->
```

and it work fine,i want to use Form::select but it doesn't work can anyone help me please

Comment: Check the documentation: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: hi sir thanks, i check it but they don't put how to select from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you would want the following to fetch `$listPatient`

```
$listPatient = Patient::lists("nom_patient","id")->toArray();
```

and in your view you would want

```
{!! Form::select('patient_id', [0 => 'Veillier séléctionner un patien'] + $listPatient, null) !!}
```

Comment: hi thans sur , i try it and i get error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: thanaanks siir it work fine now , i just want to show prenom_patient also because now show just the name thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You can upvote the answer so that it can be a reference for future users.

Comment: yes of course ,sir i try this $listPatient = Patient::lists("nom_patient","prenom_patient","id")->toArray(); but is show me just (nom_patient)

Comment: it seems you can only have 2 fields within lists i.e. `lists('nom_patient','id')` as arrays have only key and value.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution

```
enter code here :    <div class ="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('list_patient', trans('validation.attributes.backend.consultations.nom_patient'), ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label required']) }}
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <select id="patient_id" name="patient_id" class="form-control select2 box-size" required="required" placeholder=" Non définie" >
            <option value="">Non définie</option>
                @foreach($listPatient as $key)

                    <option value ="{{$key->id}}">{{$key->nom_patient}} {{$key->prenom_patient}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
            </div><!--col-lg-3-->
    </div><!--form control-->
```